# USB Wireless keyboard and wired mouse do not power on at system boot

Tags: 12.04, usb, keyboard, mouse

This did not use to be an issue but, I am not sure why, my USB keyboard and mouse are not powering on after system boot. I can fix the keyboard by taking out and then plugging back in the USB antennae, which makes it work right away, but the mouse, even if I un-plug it and plug it back in, it takes about two-three minutes until it receives any juice and starts working.

Any ways I can debug this, or fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with the USB Printer driver, once I unplugged it it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the mouse you are using , is it a combo with the keyboard and only one receiver?

Also , you may want to look at HIDpoint which is the adaptation of the logitech drivers for linux : http://www.hidpoint.com/hidpoint/overview/overview.html